# Why would I want to use Angular with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, web

I'm a studying CS and lately I've got myself really enjoying learning about web development..

Now, I have tried to learn AngularJS for a few times but then I wanted to focus more on backend first, since I already know the stuff like html/css/js which makes good part of frontend so wanted to see what backend feels like..

So I started learning Rails.. Now, since with my previous attempts of trying to learn AngularJS I learned that it is all about MVC, sending data from one to another etc.. My problem is, at first glance at least, Rails seems to work in the really similar fashion. The question is, why would anyone want to use both AngularJS and Rails at the same time, when, at least in the newbie's eyes -> Rails seems that it can handle both backend and frontend? Like, views are our frontend, and we can use css/js in those .html.erb files, wouldn't that be considered frontend after all?

Now, I'm almost positive there is a good answer to this since googling "why use angular with rails" usually comes with results of tutorials that explain to you how to integrate them, I just want some reasons so that I wouldn't be as confused as right now..

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this really is the not the right place to be asking a question like this. StackOverflow is designed to be used when you have a specific programming problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is an interesting question (and answered by a couple of people below), but I'm afraid that it isn't the usual kind of question we tend to like on Stack Overflow. It's not that it isn't interesting or useful - just that Stack Overflow is aimed towards solving specific, technical questions, rather than "why would I choose framework X"? kind of open questions. The reason for this is that in the past, these kinds of questions have caused all kinds of flame wars... so now we tend to try and avoid that where possible.

Comment: The reason I'm telling you this is that your question is likely going to be voted to be closed very shortly - and I hope you won't take it too personally. Like I said  it's interesting, and you even got an answer or two! but  it just doesn't fit the S/O template very well. I do hope you'll stick around and ask any other questions you might have :)

Comment: So, where do we ask such conceptual questions ? :(

Comment: Taryn East, thanks for feedback, you're really kind! :) I'm aware that this is more of an open question than some others, and to be honest I hesitated for a bit before posting it, but in my eyes no flame wars should ever happen with this question because I'm not asking is it better to use X or Y, I am simply asking why should one use X with Y, and from googling I already get it that we should, so I still believe this answer does have an answer indeed, it's perhaps not as open as it might look at the first glance. In the end, if it does get closed, I'm really sorry. But I couldn't find answer:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails is a server-side framework that produces HTML, JSON, and JavaScript as well as manages CSS and image assets.

AngularJS is a client-side framework. Generally, without a server component it really can't do much.

By default Rails doesn't have a client-side framework. You can use EmberJS, Angular, or others to make your client-side interface more responsive and flexible. Rails alone can't do this, it can't run in your browser.

Likewise, AngularJS can't run on your server. You need to combine them.

Comment: To both **tadman** and **Skeptor** so in the end the only reason why someone will use AngularJS with Rails is purely based on aesthetics and creating a better user experience? Like I've seen demos of twitter-alike sites being built purely in Rails, and if that's possible I can see quite a few other possibilities for a web app sort of thing.. But now that I think, isn't frontend all about aesthetics after all? I guess a lot web apps can be built using backend + forms + buttons, the jQuery for example is the one responsible for slickness.. Correct me again if I'm wrong, still learning :/

Comment: Rails alone can't do much more than HTML. You need JavaScript to push it beyond that. You can write it using only basic JavaScript (annoying), with jQuery (better), or with a front-end toolkit like AnguarJS if you're doing a lot of scripting. With HTML alone all you can do is reload pages. With JavaScript you can have real-time interaction, and AngularJS makes this sort of thing a lot easier to do.

Comment: So technically it's all about a better user experience, but sometimes it enables functionality that's impossible or impractical without scripting. Keep in mind, there's nothing that says we need images or CSS, but sites look pretty awful without them. Today the same is true for JavaScript.

Comment: Alright, thank you **tadman** for quick but detailed replies.. I get it now, in the end I didn't really knew there were such limitations for rails's layout/view(html) part.. Thank you again :) And really sorry all for creating trouble by posting such question, I'll try to be more strict in future.. But in my defense I really couldn't find an answer on google, every time I tried looking for one I'd get spammed by all the tutorials on how to combine them, not a page describing why you should do it.. :)

Comment: No trouble. The whole web thing is pretty confusing to someone who's approaching it from anew. Glad I could help.

Comment: One more point why frontend development is preferred, In application where views are loaded from backend, everytime you load a page, whole bunch of elements get loaded each time . You need to fetch them server and thats an overload. Slows down the application. IF its built using front end, only required data alone is fetched from backend.

Answer (score 0):

MVC at frontend is a recent development. Earlier days we used to develop everything at backend and use frontend only for animation, UI etc., 
Slowly with Ajax introduction we started doing more at frontend and less at backend. 
Now we migrated completely to frontend. We use backend only for logics which should be decided at server side and database management.

Single line answer, we need rails or any backend only to serve few logics which SHOULD happen in the backend, User can change the logic if it is at client side. So we force them to happen in the server side. And ofcourse database should be at the backend.

Other than that , there is absolutely no need to use rails views and others.